# How to use req.get_body() in azure function in python and what is purpose?

Tags: python, azure, https, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I am new in Azure function. I'm unable to understand what is the purpose of `req.get_body()` in azure function?? Can we pass binary image content in local host api(e.g-`http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTrigger1`) by using req.get_body()?? If yes, Please tell me how to pass binary image content in local host.
I'm trying it with `name = req.params.get('name')`. But problem is that if image content is small then i can pass successfully but if image content is large it show error.

Please help me out

Comment: I'm a little confused about the description above. May I know if you do not know how to pass the binary in "Post" method ? Do you always test your localhost function in browser with "Get" method ?

Comment: if image content is around 4kb then  I can easily pass my image content by using get method. it's work fine.

Comment: Please refer to the solution I provided below. If I misunderstood your requirement, please let me know.

Comment: If the solution helps you problem, please [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) (click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks in advance~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as you mentioned in question, "Get" method request can just be used with small request parameter. If your image content is large, we'd better to use "Post" method to request the function and put the binary in the request body of "Post" request. Apart from this, "Post" method is more security than "Get" method request.

When you test in local, you just need to use "Postman" to do it. Download "[Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/)" and do it like below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @ShivamChauhan You do not need to do any extra operation if you create the function with default code. You just need to download the postman and test the request like the screenshot I provided.

Comment: @ShivamChauhan If met any problem when you test, please provide your function code, I will help you solve it.

Comment: Can you please provide me a link where i can chat with you regarding this problem???I'll show you what i have done yet and what i'm trying to do?? Or this is my mail id #shivamchauhan20sep@gmail.com. we can communicate there .

Comment: def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
        
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')
    
    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(name)
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully",
             status_code=200
        )

Comment: I have downloaded postman and do same as you said. This message is shown `414URI Too Long`.

Comment: @ShivamChauhan Sorry for delay reply, I will test it in my side with your function code. May I know how large is your image binary ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230921/discussion-between-hury-shen-and-shivam-chauhan).

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of req.get_body() is to retrieve the data from the post request that is made.

For example, if you make a get request to your azure function at `http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTrigger`, and you write
`{ "message" :" Success" }`

And if you did something similar to this in your function:

```
import json

import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

  
    message = req.get_body()
   
   
 
    return func.HttpResponse(f"Received the message: {message}", status_code=200)
```

You would receive as a reply the message "SUCCESS" which was sent by Postman or similar.